# Apache PHP .ini.php showing as text?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mac

I have a bunch of files that are causing me problems. I am working locally on my Mac and I have files called `something.ini.php` and they are being shown as text, while my `something.php` files are coming up fine.

How can I get my `something.ini.php` to be processed as PHP?

My PHP part

```
<IfModule php5_module>
    AddHandler php5-script .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the IfModule wrappers and restart apache.  you will quickly see if apache knows about your necessary directives.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are telling it to use the type, but have you loaded the module? Something like: LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should add the line `AddHandler php5-script .php` and restart Apache:

```
<IfModule php5_module>
    AddHandler php5-script .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```